# Using fb.api calls with jquery deferred

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just cannot get my head around deferred objects

```
dfd = new $.Deferred();
FB.api('/me/posts?fields=id,story&access_token='+accessToken,function(response){          
    dfd.resolve();  
    //Do something with the result  
});
dfd.done(alert(dfd.isDeferred()));
```

From my understanding the `.done` should only fire once the request is completed and the callback sets the object as resolved, however the alert box is firing false before the request completes.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing the last line of code to :

```
dfd.done(function(){ alert(dfd.isDeferred()); });
```

This is how the use of the `done()` function is [documented in the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)